# docker service update detect automatic rollback

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, docker-swarm

I use Gitlab CI/CD to deploy new images to staging server when I make a new commit. In my pipeline the essential part is

```
docker service update my_service --update-failure-action rollback --image my_image:latest
```

Sometime the deployment fails then the automatic rollback kicks in. However `docker service update` always returns 0, so in my pipeline I have no way to know whether the deployment was successful or not.

How can I detect if deployment was really successful / if there was a rollback?

Answer (score 2):

For get update status you can run:

```
docker service inspect my_service --format "{{.UpdateStatus.State}}"
```